# Number agreement for negation and "or"

Tags: grammatical-number, articles, verb-agreement, count

Which is correct/preferred:

> There is no such thing as a base -1 or base 0 number representation.
>
> There are no such things as base -1 or base 0 number representations.
>
> There is no such thing as base -1 or base 0 number representation.

For the intended audience, "base *x* number representation" is a term of art, so both "There is no such thing as base -1 number representation" and "There is no such thing as a base -1 number representation" (with the indefinite article "a") would be used, with the former perhaps being more common.

Comment: Pick the first.

Comment: (there's no base 1 either)

Comment: @AmI - Sure there is. It's also called the [unary numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system). Pick a symbol (say, "1") and represent a natural number *n* by repeating the symbol *n* times. It fits in nicely with the other place-value systems because every place has value 1 (since 1^i = 1 for every i).

Comment: But it doesn't fit in perfectly -- unary should not be equated with base 1.

Comment: @AmI - In theory you are right. However, pretty much everyone does equate the two (including the Wikipedia article I linked to). It is a special case, of course, since there's no 0 and, because there's no scaling, no meaning to a decimal point. That's why it's only usable for representing natural numbers.

Comment: You got my point ;)

Comment: If you think similar wording in English makes a statement valid in maths, please say so. I think broadly, English is general; Maths, absolutely specific.

Your Question was about negation and *or* but two problems:

Base -1 has nothing to do with *negation* or anything like it.

Then *or* doesn’t appear in your explanatory details.

Further what is your *term of art*, please?

If *the indefinite article “a”* makes some difference in maths or technical English, please explain how.

Back at base, what has your Question to do with *number agreement*, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - The second and third examples differ only in number. So part of the question is which is proper: "There is no such thing as X or Y"  or "There are no such things as X or Y" (where each of X and Y is a singular thing). The first example has to do with whether the article "a" is properly used in this context. As to _term of art_, this is a phrase with a standard meaning (see, e.g., [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/term-of-art)).

Comment: Doesn’t your explanation of unary contradict itself? Are you suggesting the difference between *1* as in 1, 11… and the tally marks |, ||… is not conceptual but typographic?
To the extent your Wiktionary numeric systems, as opposed to the individual number *3*, the idea falls apart before 4 being 四, but at the clear stylistic difference between 二 and 三.
When I was at school, the whole point of tally systems was that Users didn’t need to understand numbers.

Comment: Ted, while it's obvious in retrospect I'm 62 and I've never once noticed the phrase *term of art* nor anything like that.

Comment: Ted, how will it cause any problem to drop *number representation* and work with *There is no such thing as a base -1 or base 0*, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - I'm not sure how my explanation of unary contradicts itself. As explained in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_marks), tally marks are a kind of unary numeral system. In a pure unary representation, 4 is 1111 (or ****, etc. depending on the mark one uses). Tally marks are not clustered in any way, so symbols like 四 are not used. As far as dropping "number representation", that works when it's clear from context that "base -1" refers to a number representation system, but I think it would be necessary to also drop the article "a".

Comment: Ted, I learned about tally marks young enough not to question such things; prolly about six years old.

Again, are you suggesting the difference between 1 as in 1, 11… and the tally marks |, ||… is not conceptual but typographic?

To the extent your Wiktionary link talks about numeric systems, as opposed to the individual number 3, the idea falls apart before 4 being 四; at the clear stylistic difference between 二 and 三. When I was at school, the whole point of tally systems was that Users didn’t need to understand numbers.

Comment: By the way, what's most clear from your link is that not everyone - including the authors - understand the difference - or even that there is a difference - between tally marks and number systems.

￼In that link, nothing after 3 is a tally mark. 4 and beyond are numerals. Don't you recognize a difference?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - Yes, I'm saying that the difference is typographic, at least when it comes to the most primitive type of tally mark representation. I'm not sure what you're seeing in the Wikipedia article, but it clearly describes all the non-tally marks as forms of tally mark clustering. Nothing breaks down or falls apart before 4, and 4 is not 四 but simply ||||. (I don't even see 四 on that page, so I don't know where you're getting that from.)

Comment: It’s not typographic. *1* isn’t *i* or *I* or any scratch mark.

Sorry, I followed Wiki's links from your primary reference to wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_marks. 

Another way, *tallying* isn't a *unary* or any *numerary* system; it's purely graphic.

Crucial is what happens at milestones like 5, which your Wiki says is 11111… purely graphic, despite Wiki’s typography. Four strokes and the diagonal *gate*  I can't yet post are cuspal.

A diagonal fifth stroke could still be graphic. A symbolic diagonal is numeric.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - In the unary number representation, the "1" is not numeric; it's purely a graphical indicator of presence. In Wikipedia's language, it's "an arbitrarily chosen symbol representing 1". The fact that the symbol happens to _be_ 1 is irrelevant. It could just as well be ◼︎ or anything else. Also, there are no diagonal strokes in the unary number representation (although there could be clustering via variable spacing between marks to improve readability).

Comment: Thanks Ted and yes, I've telling you the *1* isn't numeric. It's also not an arbitrary symbol. It's at best extremely badly chosen and at least as likely to confuse as to enlighten. That's no more your fault than mine.

That *unary system* almost sounds reasonable and I suggest it's not much more likely you've seen 137 or even 28 represented as iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii than I have. Can you find an example or three, outside theory?